# Draw a grid of images onto a JPanel using Graphics, and then add that JPanel to a JFrame multiple times without redrawing the images each time?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am currently trying to draw a large grid of Images onto a JPanel, and then add that panel to a JFrame 60 times per second. I have this functioning while drawing to the panel created by the class having "extends JPanel", and drawing to that JPanel using paintComponent(Graphics g). However, the problem with this is that, because the class is being called 60 times per second (with paintComponent being re-called each time), the application can only run at around 2-3fps. The solution I came up with was to use the following code to draw the image to the JPanel only once by creating a drawing method which must be manually called, and then simply adding that JPanel onto the JFrame 60 times per second.

```
public class Testing extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testing.run(frame); //This is called by another class in the program
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panelContainingDrawnImages;
    Image[][] MAP; // Initialized based on the world.txt file it receives

    public void tick() { // Is called 60 times a second
        frame.add(this); // Add the class's main panel, - which now has the Images painted to it - to the frame used by all classes in the application
    }

    public void drawImageToPanel(Graphics g) {
        for (int c = 0; c < MAP.length; c++) { // The x axis of the game's map
            for (int r = 0; r < MAP[c].length; r++) { // The y axis of the game's map
                g.drawImage(MAP[c][r], xPos, yPos, null);
            }
        }
    }

    public void run(JFrame frame) {
        frame = this.frame; // The JFrame from this method is passed in from another class
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        drawImageToPanel(g);
    }
}
```

However, for some reason, the line

```
Graphics g = getGraphics();
```

returns null, and therefore the call to

```
drawImageToPanel(g);
```

fails, returning a NullPointerException as soon as any graphics are drawn.

My question is: How can I draw a bunch of Images to a JPanel only once, whilst calling a JFrame.add(panel) method many many times (60 times per second). This doesn't seem to be possible using paintComponent(), as that runs every time the class.tick() - which is called 60 times per second - is called, meaning the 2D array of Images is drawn over and over again, meaning the program runs at only a few fps instead of the desired 60fps. I'm also struggling to accomplish this using a drawing method which has to be called manually, as

```
g = getGraphics();
```

just returns null. What can I do?

Comment: Why are you adding a static panel a **second** time, let alone **60 times per second?!?** General tips: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) 3) `Graphics g = getGraphics();` See the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) lesson of the tutorial for the correct way to go about custom painting a component.

Comment: "`g = getGraphics();`
just returns null. What can I do?" -- don't use an unstable evanescent object such as a Graphics object obtained in this way. Instead follow the tutorials and @AndrewThompson's advice. It will be the same advice that you'll find in numerous Q/A's on this site.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"don't use an unstable evanescent object such as a Graphics object obtained in this way."* Yes, good point that I forgot to mention! Another thing I forgot to mention is that if there is a complex, static scene (e.g. used as a background) that needs to be used for every frame, I'd typically **render it into a `BufferedImage` that can be used for each paint.**

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes exactly, and perhaps using the `repaint(...)` overload that limits the area being repainted might help as well

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you both so much! The linked tutorial on painting was very helpful, and I was able to use it to help correct the stupid mistakes I was making. I will also definitely render the Images to a BufferedImage. Have a great day, and thanks again for the help!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels As part of the above message. Thank you :)